# Survivor Space suddenly growing and increasing response times

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I have a web application deployed on a wildfly-10.1.0 application server and doing some load tests with jmeter. At a certain user count for a short amount of time response times grow rapidly and plunge to a low level again. This behavior repeats itself several times. Interesting about this is that the size of the survivor space of the wildlfy jvm is consistent with the response time ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inZxK.png)).

I already tried tuning the heap sizes of the wildfly jvm and of the young and old generation but the behavior stays the same. Has anyone an idea as to what leads the survivor space to grow in such a way and what I have to change in order to keep my response times low?

Comment: what is wildfly jvm?

Comment: wildfly is the application server my web application is running on... what I mean is the jvm the wildfly server is running in

Comment: no one can tell you what take more memory just with the information you wrote

Comment: record detailed GC logs, upload them somewhere. state your jvm version and used VM flags.

Answer (score -1):

> http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html
>
> Major garbage collection are also Stop the World events. Often a major collection is much slower because it involves all live objects. So for Responsive applications,major garbage collections should be minimized.

keep your objects life time as small as possible, objects with long life time tends to be moved to old gen (survivor), old gen require **major garbage collection** to perform GC.